# Academic CV: Including declined postdoctoral fellowships under "Awards and Honors"?

Tags: funding, cv

I have seen many people list declined graduate fellowships from big tech giants, NSF, etc., on their CVs. Many of these are respected researchers working as tenure-track faculty in top-tier R1 institutes. I don't have such fellowships that I have declined, but I did get multiple postdoctoral fellowships (all from very good places) that I did decline (to accept my top-choice postdoc).

I wanted to ask if it looks obnoxious to list these under "Awards and Honours".

I am sure this varies with context, so here's the context: I'm applying for travel grants with the AMS and also for some summer school short courses.

My reason for wanting to list these declined fellowships is to signal that multiple places thought I was good enough to be offered a postdoc. I didn't get any graduate fellowships, and my "Awards and Honors" section otherwise looks quite scarce, with only minor travel grants. That's why I thought I'd add these postdoc fellowships (they are all I have).

Of course, though, I do get that this can look really icky; I'm not entirely sure though since I have seen senior people do  it. I thought I'd check here. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an 'Awards and Honours' section of my CV. Sounds like there is several lines worth of space better devoted to something a potential employer might actually care about.